# Problem in insertion of a new class in the open-source project called MovingPandas

Tags: python, open-source

For the last few days, I'm trying to work on an open-source project called movingPandas written in Python. After the clone and installation of the framework on my machine (Windows 10), I tried to create a new class in a new file e.g. MyClass in the file myclass.py. After that, I restarted the kernel, imported the necessary packages and I tried to instantiate my class. But a got an attribute error, as follows:

```
AttributeError: module 'movingpandas' has no attribute 'MyClass'
```

What am I doing wrong? I must declare the new class somewhere in the project?
It is the first time that I'm trying to contribute to an open-source project and I would appreciate any help.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you add `MyClass` into the `__init__.py` file?

Comment: You are the best. It worked. Thanks a lot. I really appreciate it